# Limit write_xlsx rows in RStudio

Tags: powerbi

I have added an R script within PowerBI to download the records into excel. I have used the xlsx library. The file is generated very well, but I have noticed that it only exports 150,000 rows and I want to export almost 400K rows or more, is this possible through some additional data within the code?

The download must be done with R language.

El script es:

```r
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dataset,"D:\\Report_Vulns.xlsx", format_headers = TRUE, use_zip64 = TRUE)
```